# Webform multiple files with descriptions

Tags: forms, webforms, files

D7: I am looking at building a competition section on a site I'm working on. Originally I started looking at Webforms to do this, but there are requirements I have that Webform doesn't solve (as far as I can tell).

What I need is to allow entrants to submit images. There must be at least 5 and no more than 12. Each image submitted should have a title, a caption and a date (dd/mm/yyyy). This is a big problem because I can only find two modules that allow for multiple file uploads in Webforms, neither allow specifying a minimum number of files and neither allow text fields and a date to be entered with each image.

Does anyone know a way I can solve this in Webform or do I need to look at building something custom? It's a pain that I can meet 80% of the requirements out of the box (kinda).

Answer (score 0):

You can allow node submission for users. Create a content type, go to permissions tab and allow content type to be submitted by particular user role. Under content type go to manage fields and create an image field by allowing multiple images to be uploaded. Now use [Form block module](https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock) to display node form on front end for users. This will be easy for you as well as you can get the submitted content easily in views to display them as per your requirement.